# How to download all URLs retrieved in a tab (Google Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, url

Is there a way to download all the URLs which are called when I access a website in Chrome?
I don't want to download the files inside the URLs, but I want to get the list of URLs which are called.

Comment: If you're looking to extract the linked URLs in a webpage, then see [How to Extract Links from a Webpage in Windows](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-extract-links-from-a-webpage-in-windows/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
You should click "Save all as HAR with content" in the Network tab

[image of Network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1LoT.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need an extension for that.

One such extension is
[Link Grabber](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-grabber/caodelkhipncidmoebgbbeemedohcdma):

[image]